# What's the real use of `FormProtection` if `$_accessible` is correctly used in Entities in CakePhp4?

Tags: forms, security, cakephp-4.x

In almost every projects I have to disable the `FormProtection` on front side forms to avoid a `BadRequestException` (when a user leaves a form open for a while before submitting) and I'm wondering what the real point of keeping `FormProtection` enabled if sensitive fields (like ids) are set to false in `$_accessible` in entities ?

Answer (score 0):

The FormProtection also ensures that no fields are removed by the client.
So lets if your controller relies on a specific input-field you can be sure its there or the user gets an error.

From CakePHPs documentation:
By default the FormProtectionComponent prevents users from tampering with forms in specific ways. It will prevent the following things:

- Form’s action (URL) cannot be modified.
- Unknown fields cannot be added to the form.
- Fields cannot be removed from the form.
- Values in hidden inputs cannot be modified.

https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/components/form-protection.html#form-tampering-prevention